# Using output_style = :compressed breaks Susy layout

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I understand that using different CSS compression shouldn't really have any effect on the site outcome (except smaller file size) but my site breaks completely when I set Compass to spit out compressed CSS.

I'm not sure what it is that breaks, but I believe it's Susy that collides with some other Compass function like the sprite or base64 inline image functions.

In order to not paste too much code in this question, here are two links to demonstrate (same source, generated seconds apart)

Using **output_style = :expanded** in config.rb (everything works):
http://davidpaulsson.se/expanded/

Using **output_style = :compressed** in config.rb (layout breaks):
http://davidpaulsson.se/compressed/

I'm using Jekyll to generate the static files, and the source files are available on Github: https://github.com/davidpaulsson/davidpaulsson.se/tree/master/sass

Comment: Please share your source SASS code via http://sassbin.com (edit your post and write a follow-up comment here for me to notice).

Comment: You must provide enough code - here in the question - to demonstrate the problem.  Putting code in an off-site demo (like JSfiddle or Codepen) is a nice-to-have, and may help people understand your question more easily.

Comment: I'm not actually seeing any difference between the two demos. Is it browser-specific?

Comment: @EricMeyer: yea, I see now that this is a browser issue. I use Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95, and this is where I see the problem. In Firefox it works. But not in Safari, so webkit is handling something differently.

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov: Here's the SASS code: https://github.com/davidpaulsson/davidpaulsson.se/tree/master/sass

Comment: And here's a video demo of the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu0NF6B4Mos

Comment: The asker has provided the code. I've found the problem and willing to answer. @DavidPaulsson, please edit your post and link to the sources from there. Everybody please vote for reopening.

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov Sorry, I can't (since I don't have enough rep point, I can't add any more links).

Comment: Uhm, okay, you've got erroneous CSS in [line 208 of _general.scss](https://github.com/davidpaulsson/davidpaulsson.se/blob/8cdd040637dc686a91cdbb0a06c641d6449bb4d1/sass/bits/_general.scss#L208). You've got a CSS declaration without a selector. Unfortunately, Sass compiler fails to halt at this error, maybe because it's inside a `@media` block.

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov I re-opened if you want to give a more detailed/official answer.

Comment: Thank you Eric, you're awesome as always. I've given my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code ([_general.scss, line 208](https://github.com/davidpaulsson/davidpaulsson.se/blob/8cdd040637dc686a91cdbb0a06c641d6449bb4d1/sass/bits/_general.scss#L208)):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {  
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
```

Here you have a CSS declaration without a selector, which is invalid.

SASS should've produced an error. Maybe it failed to do so because of the `@media` wrapper which kinda looks like a selector.

I'm not sure what this CSS property does, try applying it to `html` or `*`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    }
}
```